# I'm not sure what is incorrect about my query statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

This is the query statement I wrote.  I'm trying to get and print all post where the value of `requestor == current_user.id`

```
@posts = Post.joins(user: :follows).where(follows: { requestor: current_user.id }).order(created_at: :desc)
```

Currently, this query statement is only printing out the post of the `current.id` and multiplying each by the number of requestors listed.

`requestor` is part of the `:follows` table which contains a `user.id`.  I will post the follows and posts tables below.  The user's tables uses basic devise.

```
# Table name: follows
#
#  id         :bigint           not null, primary key
#  following  :bigint
#  requestor  :bigint
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  user_id    :bigint
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_follows_on_user_id  (user_id)
#
# Foreign Keys
#
#  fk_rails_...  (user_id => users.id)
#
```

```
# Table name: posts
#
#  id         :bigint           not null, primary key
#  attachment :string
#  content    :text
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  user_id    :bigint
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_posts_on_user_id  (user_id)
#
# Foreign Keys
#
#  fk_rails_...  (user_id => users.id)
#
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

This is the view loop.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
    

            <th>Attachment</th>
            <th>Content</th>
            <th></th>
            
          <th></th>
        
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @posts.each do |post| %>
        <%= content_tag :tr, id: dom_id(post), class: dom_class(post) do %>
          

                      <td><%= post.attachment %></td>
                      <td><%= post.content %></td>
          
          
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>

          
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Add the association of users and sample input and output of table data

Comment: The association was already present.  There is two has_many association in the user model one for follow and one for post.  I added some sample output data to the post.

Comment: Can you post the loop in your view code? I suspect that's where your problem is.

Comment: I just added the loop in the view.

Comment: @Isaiah I ask you to give sample input and output data of the table. I don't understand what  have you added